# Sort by two conditions

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, search

I have an array of **n** objects with fields: ID, price. Identical IDs may occur more than once in an array. I want to find the cheapest **k** and no more than **m** objects for each IDs.

At the same time, k <= n, m <= k.

Like:

```
n = 1,000,000
k = 10,000
m = 50
```

```java
class Issue {
    int ID;
    int price;

    public Issue(int ID, int price) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
Issue[] arr = {
    new Issue(1, 100),
    new Issue(1, 150),
    new Issue(1, 200),

    new Issue(2, 1),
    new Issue(2, 2),
    new Issue(2, 3),

    new Issue(3, 4),
    new Issue(3, 5),
    new Issue(3, 30),
    new Issue(3, 6),

    new Issue(4, 7),
    new Issue(4, 8),
    new Issue(4, 9),
    new Issue(4, 10),
};
```

If:

```
n = 14
k = 5
m = 2
```

decision like:

```
new Issue(2, 1),
new Issue(2, 2),
new Issue(3, 4),
new Issue(3, 5),
new Issue(4, 7),
```

I solved this problem using java streams, but using several sorts and O comes out bad. What would you suggest an algorithm to solve?

@Xiangpeng thanks for the answer. Do you mean it?

```java
        int k = 5; // only k cheapest from array n
        int m = 2; //max same iDs
        Map<Integer, PriorityQueue<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        stream(arr).forEach(product -> {
            if (!map.containsKey(product.ID)) {
                PriorityQueue<Integer> integers = new PriorityQueue<>(reverseOrder());
                integers.add(product.price);
                map.put(product.ID, integers);
            } else {
                PriorityQueue<Integer> integers = map.get(product.ID);
                integers.add(product.price);
                map.put(product.ID, integers);
                if (integers.size() > m) {
                    integers.poll();
                }
            }
        });
        PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueueK = new PriorityQueue<>(k, reverseOrder());
        for (PriorityQueue<Integer> values : map.values()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ) {
                priorityQueueK.add(values.poll());
                if (priorityQueueK.size() > k) {
                    priorityQueueK.poll();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this homework? Have you tried using a custom `Comparator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the priority queue structure.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

For each ID, make a map ID -> [ priority queue of size **m**], size m means do a `poll` each time you add a price when there are already **m** prices.

There are then at most **m** prices for each ID, take this map and build another [ priority queue of size **k** ] you will solve the problem.

Complexity is O(n*log(k))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean it? I edit the description of the issue.

Comment: `PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueueK = new PriorityQueue<>(k, reverseOrder());` Perhaps here we don't need to tell it to be of `k` size in the initialisation ?
Also if you want your final result to be price with ID, then you may need to create object of (ID, price) and add comparator to compare price for `priorityQueueK` step .
Otherwise in terms of complexity, right, I mean it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to accept my answer if you think it's good ?
I want to have more than 15 reputations to vote for other answers indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a comparator with two conditions.

***Comparator.comparing((Issue a) -> a.ID )*** create a new comparator by ID

***thenComparing*** add a second condition, in this case compare price

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing((Issue a)-> a.ID ).thenComparing((a,b)-> Integer.compare(a.price, b.price) ));
```

i suggest use getters and setters methods

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing((Issue a)-> a.getId() ).thenComparing((a,b)-> Integer.compare(a.getPrice(), b.getPrice()) ));
```

Comment: This is hardly a solution. We need only k objects from the array n, with no more than m identical IDs. Where k <= n, m <= k. How does this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to sort the issues by price, then iterate over them, keeping track of how many issues you've already selected with a given ID (so that you can skip any issues over the limit). Once you've selected the right number of issues, abort.

So:

```
Collections.sort(arr, (issueA, issueB) => Integer.compare(issueA.price, issueB.price));

final List<Issue> result = new ArrayList<>();
final Map<Integer, Integer> countsByID = new HashMap<>();

for (final Issue issue : arr) {
    if (! countsByID.containsKey(issue.ID)) {
        countsByID.put(issue.ID, 0);
    }

    if (countsByID.get(issue.ID) >= m) {
        continue;
    }

    result.add(issue);

    countsByID.put(issue.ID, countsByID.get(issue.ID) + 1);

    if (result.size() == k) {
        return result;
    }
}

return result; // couldn't find k values satisfying the restrictions
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about O() this solution?

Comment: @LongMap: It's O(n log n), because of the sort; the rest is O(n).